# Can I use git to remove a file somebody else put in the repository that I never use?

Tags: git

At work we use git as source control.  In one folder, there is a script I use very often, but there are several other scripts in the folder that are very similarly named that I never use.  These other scripts make it difficult for me to tab-complete the name of my script when I want to run it, making it a minor annoyance every time I run this script.

I was hoping that I could put the names of the other scripts in my global .gitignore file, then delete them, but git still recognized that I had removed them, and wants me to commit this change.

In order to solve the problem, I have just created a bash alias for my script name, but it still leaves me curious whether the problem could have been solved another way.  Is it possible for me to remove a file from my local git repository without having git complain?

Answering "No" is acceptable.  I just am not sure whether I failed because it isn't possible, or because my git fu is not strong enough.

Comment: Do I understand correctly: you want to delete it from the file system, but it not be deleted from the repo?

Comment: Whatever the solution is, if it involves `.gitignore` make sure your `.gitignore` includes ".gitignore" so your preference doesn't propagate to the rest of the team. *(paging Xzibit...)*

Comment: @jayraynet Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `git-update-index --assume-unchanged path/to/ignored/file`.  That will keep git from checking that file for changes in your local working tree, but not affect any remote repositories.